# argument of type "double" is incompatible with parameter of type "double *"

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, parameters, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass the pointer to a data structure  member into a function. I am passing 4 variable and the two string members are being passed but the two double members keep giving the this error. I don''t understand why this is causing an error.

The prototype:

```
void InputEmployeeData(std::string *LastName, std::string *FirstName, double *HrsWrkd, double *PayRate);
```

My Main function:

```
 int main()
    {
        EmployeeRecord *ptr, Employees;
        ptr = &Employees;

        InputEmployeeData(ptr->LastName, ptr->FirstName, ptr->HrsWrkd, ptr->PayRate);
    }
```

The function:

```
void InputEmployeeData(std::string *LastName, std::string *FirstName, double *HrsWrkd, double *PayRate)
{
    /*Input module that requests employee's first name, last name, hours worked, and pay*/

    std::cout << "Enter employee's first name: ";
    std::cin >> *FirstName;
    std::cout << "Enter employee's last name: ";
    std::cin >> *LastName;

    std::cout << "Enter number of hours worked: ";
    std::cin >> *HrsWrkd;

    std::cout << "Enter hourly pay rate: ";
    std::cin >> *PayRate;
}
```

Comment: What's actually unclear about the error message? A `double` value isn't the same as a `double*` pointer.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of `EmployeeRecord` is missing, but according to your code, it appear that it would be expected to be something like:

```
class EmployeeRecord {
      ...
   public: 
      string *LastName;     // all pointers ?
      string *FirstName; 
      double *HrsWrkd; 
      double *PayRate;
      ...
};
```

But this would require some manual memory management to create member objects using `new`, before storing some values.  Is it really like this ?

Certainly not completely.  Because according to the error message -- and assuming that there's really no problem with the `string*` parameters -- you seem to have:

```
class EmployeeRecord {
      ...
   public: 
      string *LastName;
      string *FirstName; 
      double HrsWrkd;        // no pointers, but values
      double PayRate;
      ...
};
```

In this case you should change your call to:

```
// note the use of & to get the pointer to the object
InputEmployeeData(ptr->LastName, ptr->FirstName, &ptr->HrsWrkd, &ptr->PayRate);
```

Now this being said,  I'd recommend in this case to also change the `string*` to `string` to avoid unnecessary manual memory management. You should really need no pointer in this kind of class.  In this case, you'll have to use `&` for all the parameters.

Even better: not only get rid of the pointers in EmployeeRecord, but consider passing the arguments by reference:

```
void InputEmployeeData(std::string& LastName, std::string& FirstName, double& HrsWrkd, double& PayRate)
{
    ... 
    std::cin >> FirstName;   // no use of pointer dereferencing * anymore
                             // the reference will make sure the original object
                             // passed by reference will be modified
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error from the compiler is very clear. When the type of argument is `double*`, you must not use a  `double` object in a call to the function.

You can change the call to the function

```
InputEmployeeData(&(ptr->LastName), &(ptr->FirstName), &(ptr->HrsWrkd), &(ptr->PayRate));
```

to remove the compiler errors.

However, it is better to change strategy algother.

1. Define an overload of `operator>>` function to read the data of an object from a stream. This is more idiomatic.
2. Remove the prompts from the function. Provide any prompting information before calling the `operator>>` function.
3. Use the following call to read the data, which is, to repeat myself, more idiomatic.

   ```
   EmployeeRecord employee;
   cin >> employee;
   ```

---

```
class EmployeeRecord
{
    ...

    friend std::istream operator>>(std::istream& in, EmployeeRecord& emp)
    {
       return (in >> emp.FirstName >> emp.LastName >> emp.HrsWrkd >> em.PayRate);
    }
};


int main()
{
    EmployeeRecord employee;
    std::cout << "Enter employee's first name, last name, hours workd, and pay rate.\n";
    std::cin >> employee;
}
```